# Pass object from JSONResult to other function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

How can I pass the object (or the id of my object) of my Jsonresult to another function in jQuery? I had everything working when my Actionresults returned views or other actions, but now I have to change everything to have it work in a modal and I can't get past step one.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var registerEmailBtn = $("#registerEmailBtn");

registerEmailBtn.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    SaveEmailAddress();
    $("#step1").addClass("d-none");
    $("#step2").removeClass("d-none");

});

});


function SaveEmailAddress() {
var user = {
    ID: $("#emailId").val(),
    Email: $("#emailField").val()
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    url: "/api/UserManagement/Register",
    data: JSON.stringify(user),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
}
```

When I check the console, the object with the data returned from my controller is there.

Controller Function:

```
    Function Register(user As User) As JsonResult
        user.ConfirmationCode = codeGenerator.CreateConfirmationCode()
        Dim id = _userData.AddEmailAddressLastId(user)
        user.ID = id
        Return Json(user)
    End Function
```

Output Console:

[image: Console Output]

The next step should be to confirm the code, the methods work when I return views from actionresults but I can't seem to figure out how to pass the id of my object to the methods below.

```
    <HttpGet>
    Function GetConfirmCode(Optional ByVal id As Integer = 0) As JsonResult
        Dim user As New User
        If id > 0 Then
            user = _userData.GetUserByID(id)
            user.ConfirmationCode = ""
        End If
        Return Json(user)
    End Function

    <HttpPost>
    Function ConfirmCode(Optional user As User = Nothing) As JsonResult
        Dim enteredCode = user.ConfirmationCode
        Dim givenCode = _userData.GetConfirmationCode(enteredCode)

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(givenCode) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(givenCode) Then
            TempData("ErrorMessage") = "Codes don't match"
            Return Json(user)
        End If

        user = _userData.GetUserWithConfirmationCode(givenCode)
        Return Json(New With {user.ID}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

    End Function
```

I just want to pass the ID from my register function to a confirmCode function so I can retrieve the correct record from my db. I've tried with hidden fields, but can't seem to get them populated.

HTML:

```
  @Using Html.BeginForm()

            @<div id="step1">
                @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m.ID, New With {.id = "emailId"})
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Email, New With {.id = "emailField"})
                <button class="mybtn-sm color-btn-default" id="registerEmailBtn">Volgende</button>
                <div class="code-link">
                    <a href="#">Ik heb al een uitnodigingscode ontvangen</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        End Using

        @Using Html.BeginForm()
            @<div id="step2" class="d-none">
                @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m.ID, New With {.id = "idField"})
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Email, New With {.id = "checkEmail"})
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.ConfirmationCode, New With {.id = "confCodeField"})
                <button class="mybtn-sm color-btn-default" id="confCodeBtn">Volgende</button>
            </div>
        End Using
        <div class="login-socials">
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Aanmelden met</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="social-links">
                <div class="social-link-item"><p><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>&nbsp;Facebook</p></div>
                <div class="social-link-item"><p><i class="fab fa-google"></i>&nbsp; Google</p></div>
                <div class="social-link-item"><p><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>&nbsp; linkedin</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @*<a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a>*@
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean you want to pass the result lets say confirmation code to another controller method?

Comment: @Adlorem, I want to pass the ID from my JSON result as parameter to the ConfirmCode method. That Get method accepts an optional int as parameter which retrieves the ConfirmationCode from the db from the user with the ID. From my example, ID 71 should be the parameter for the controller method ConfirmCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Register method on my controller to return the id as int instead of the object itself. In the success function of the ajax call, I set the value of a hidden field to the int that was passed. In the following method ConfirmCode, I used the value of the hidden field as parameter and modified the post method to also do the check on Id instead of using httpget and httppost.